# Logo in navbar shifts bottom left

Tags: css, navbar

Go to [Click here](http://ezeecopy.com) and make the browser smaller. The ups logo hits the bottom left corner at a certain point. I would like to fix this. Can you help?
I tried applying some differnt css to the logo using a @media screen and (`min-width:671px;`). I would like the logo to be next to the banners button when the screen is in the @media screen range.

Comment: i modified the link srry guys

Comment: Within the @media query for min-width, you actually should not have a semicolon after your px value. Your issue could be something as simple as that

Comment: I have a question about the code

 1. Why are you not using a [unordered list](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)?
 2. Your media screen size have a funny size that I don't understand why you use. Tables are 768px and phone are 576px
 3. Why are your ups logo the last `<a>` in your menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it doesnt have enough space there,try reducing the padding like,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 682px) {
    .w3-bar .w3-bar-item {
       padding: 8px 8px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man this actually fixed my problem. I really appreciate it. the only thing i had to change was this  @media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 671px) {
    .w3-bar .w3-bar-item {
       padding:8px 8px;
    }
}

Comment: Ok well it looks like the problem still exist but when i was in the developer tools on chrome it seems to work but when im out of it the problem exist:(

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: instead of my ups logo jumping to the next line when the screen gets smaller i just want it to stay inline with everything else